# How to resolve ConfuserEx warning for missing SN Keys

Tags: .net, obfuscation

I have a project with a .NET library that I obfuscated with ConfuserEx. During the protect run, I got a warning stating the following:

```
[WARN] [foo.dll] SN Key is not provided for a signed module, the output may not be working.
```

Fact is, the assembly is signed with a strong key name. However, the code seems to be running without issues afterwards.

This arises two questions:

1. How would you detect an actual issue, if the output would not work?
2. How do I have to provide the SN Key to get rid of the warning message?

Neither the documentation of the software nor the cli output gave me an indication how to include the keys. Copying the key to the same folder as the dlls did not resolve the warning.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the gui of ConfuserEx you can simply select the already added modules and edit them. In the edit mask you can add your key and the key password. Done!

[image: ConfuserEx Description how to add a key to sign the confused assemblies]

Alternatively you can directly edit the .crproj file with a texteditor and add 2 attributes `snKey` and `snKeyPass` to your module which contain the link to the key file and the password:

```
<module path="foo.dll" snKey="fooKey.pfx" snKeyPass="fooKeyPassword" />
```